# Ubuntu 14.04 not launch

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, system-installation

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04, but it is not running, when i  log in  then just a  screen with logo is seen. My system parameters:
Processor: Amd athlon 3 GHz
Memory: 4 Gb
Video: 256 Mb. Maybe all problems in video? Help me please)

Comment: Do you have some sort of a graphical interface when logging in? Something like this (http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-yB4Fp64uBjM/TmCsOZntJPI/AAAAAAAABNY/F1s8IEa_QLs/s1600/Unity+Greeter+LightDM.png)?

Comment: sure, i enter password click to login and all stops...

Comment: Ok, can you press Ctrl+ALt+F1 and check that you can login there? If so, can you type in `startx` and see whether that gives anything?

Comment: I already trying to call console, and its not working..

Comment: Define "it's not working". Can you not access tty1 (what you get when you press ctrl+alt+f1), can you not log in there, or can you not type `startx`?

Comment: i just stay on the screen with logo,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17830/discussion-between-mrhug-and-excluded-once).

Comment: Chat resulted in OP mentioning he would try Ubuntu 12.04 first to see if the problem also occurs there.

Comment: hm Ubuntu 12.04 works fine, i think all problem in small graphic memory, need new video-card... thanks for help @MrHug  :)

Comment: If that is indeed the case, it is not listed in the Systemrequirements. I would like this question to remain open to find out if someone has a better answer to this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press F6 before show logo and add command line to install -> xforcevesa and bypass  display VGA driver and install Ubuntu good.

Comment: thanks but i solve this issue just replace videocard with 512Mb memory)